# How do I set one to many relationships in lucid chart?

Tags: charts, flowchart

I have connected two shapes with a line in lucid chart. How do I show that it is one to many? Visio allows you to do this.

Comment: I submitted an edit with the new tag.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your question! I actually work for [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/), so I'm happy to help. I'm not sure if you're asking about showing a one-to-many relationship in ERD or in UML, so I'll answer both. I've described the appropriate steps below, but I've also recorded this screencast to show you the steps: https://lucidchart1.viewscreencasts.com/ac3bd4a01a1a4456948f37e532b3ed53

**ERD:**

Once you connect two shapes, you can click on the line in the middle and change the endpoints to be an arrow, crows foot, or any of our other line endings. Just click on the line and then you'll see the top options bar will change to include two drop down menus, each referring to a different endpoint of the line. You can also add multiplicities to an ERD diagram the same way you add them with UML shapes (see below for more details).

**UML:**

After you connect two shapes together with a line, you can click on the line and a dialogue box will appear. This box will give you the options to "Add Multiplicities" or "Reverse Line Direction." You can use the multiplicities to indicate how many points you are making.

Comment: Link is out of date, and I don't get a popup dialog when I select line.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still viewing this post, the way I got around the "add multiplicities" not working is by creating as much gap between the boxes as possible and double clicking the portion of the arrow I wanted to add the multiplicity/text to.

Comment: Clicking "Add Multiplicities" didn't do anything for me as well.  Performing these steps worked for me; though I wish the "Add Multiplicities" would work.